# Parsing fuzzy dates in Haskell (or C)

Tags: c, parsing, date, haskell

Is there a good library for parsing dates from a string in Haskell or ANSI C?  Something like PHP's strtotime, or Ruby's Time.parse or Chronic, or whatever.

If it can parse "next week", etc, then that's ideal, but even if it can just figure out for itself what format a complete date string is in and return the result, that would be good enough.

I'd really rather not port Chronic or extract strototime by hand...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much hunting, I discovered that the date code in Git is pretty good and not very dependent on the rest of Git, so I pulled it out and made http://hackage.haskell.org/package/git-date

I'm willing to use a better solution if there is one :)

Comment: Awesome! I've been wanting this for a while.

Comment: How about the unix date command? I'm not sure how much it can parse, but it can handle 'next week'.

Comment: You saved me a ton of time! Thanks for creating this!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't handle "next week" style stuff, but the Data.Time.Format module from the [time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) library does essentially what you want, I think, and it's included by default with the Haskell Platform.  Just scroll down the haddock docs until you get to the parsing section.

Comment: All of the parsers in that library require me to pass in a date format string.  I don't know how the dates will be formatted in advance.

Comment: @singpolyma The docs say the functions do accept "some variation".  Beyond that, just call `parseTime` (or whatever) with each possible format, separating the calls by `<|>`